# Invalid regular expression error in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

If the '[' special character is used in a regex constructor object, it throws `Invalid regular expression: /mat[/: Unterminated character class`

```
function findMatch() {
   var string="Find the match";
   var text = "Mat[";

   string.replace(new RegExp(text, 'gi'),  "found")
}
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I solve this?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Looks like the latter... Anyways, the square bracket is a reserved character in a regex. You must escape it with a preceding back-slash. Also, avoid naming variables "string"; give is a more appropriate name like "originalText".

Comment: What that reserved character mean and how to escape it. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/2955337

Comment: What is your desired output with this code? That expression (even if escaped), will replace nothing.

Comment: A backlash \ is usually the character to escape the one following, to make it a literal. [ has a meaning I regexp, which you don't want

Comment: Why use `RegExp` if not using a regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: @user3783243 It could be as a means to ignore case.

Comment: Why use regex at all, just use `string.replaceAll(text, "found")`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions use the characters `[]` to identify a character class-- to match any character within the brackets.  If you want to use either of those bracket characters as a literal, then you must escape it with a backslash.  Your goal should be the regular expression:

```
/Mat\[/
```

You'll also need to escape the backslash itself to convert from the string to a regular expression.  Thus, your code should be:

```
var text = "Mat\\[";
```

Comment: incorrect, that will produce the same error. You are just escaping that character in the string, it will not be escaped in the reg exp.

Comment: What is the correct to escape this

Comment: An oversight on my part.  Corrected.

Comment: @WebDev — backslash is an escape in Javascript, so javascript sees "Mat\[" and makes the string "Mat[" ... the open-bracket was escaped. Now you pass that "Mat[" to `new RegExp(...)` and the regex _doesn't_ see a backslash, JS took it out when it created the String object. So regex sees `Mat[` and `[` is special, and it's missing a closing bracket `]`. To get the backslash to RegExp you have to escape the escape: `var text = "Mat\\["`.  I see phatfingers corrected that while I was writing this, but thought a fuller explanation might be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

The error occurs because the square bracket character `[` has a special meaning in regular expressions. It is used to define a character class, which allows specifying a set of characters that can match at that position.

In your example, the error is occurring because the regex pattern `Mat[` is not properly terminated. The closing square bracket `]` is missing, causing the error message "Unterminated character class."

To fix this issue, you need to escape the square bracket character using a backslash `\` to treat it as a literal character instead of a special character in the regular expression.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT